# Competitive programming-related tags on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, retag-request, tag-synonym-process

We [had a longish discussion recently](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13690/the-setting-is-competition-but-the-activity-is-still-programming) over a closed proposal on Area 51 about how the [competitive programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Competitive_programming) community can profit better from the Stack Exchange network. On Stack Overflow we currently have two tags related to the topic:

- [[programming-contest]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/programming-contest)
- [[programming-competitions]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/programming-competitions)

Most of the questions however are just tagged [algorithm].

Obviously the two tags are synonyms, so at the very least we should merge them, but I also think that their names are a bit informal. As a bit of an experiment, I added the [[competitive-programming]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/competitive-programming/info) tag with a question and a small Wiki entry that tries to describe what it is about.

I have a few questions to the Stack Overflow community:

- Do we need such a tag / is it helpful? [My question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22394257/how-to-count-find-integers-between-large-a-and-b-with-a-certain-property) pretty much tries to demonstrate a technique that is really only ever useful for this one particular setting, so I thought it should be tagged that way
- Do you think it is appropriate to choose "competitive-programming" as the name for the tag or would this cause too much confusion?
- If so, can we merge the tags?
- To what extent do you think CP-related questions would be on-topic on Stack Overflow? What is *technically* the correct way to choose between SO and for example Programmers.SE or CS.SE with regard to contest problems and algorithm implementation? Please keep in mind that in many cases it is hard to separate theory and practice here, because ease of implementation is just as important as having a fast enough algorithm, so it's often better to "underdesign" an idea by sacrificing some generality in favor of implementation speed. This seems to be pretty unique to competitive programming and to me it feels like the majority of questions falls under the topic of Stack Overflow the most ("questions about **software** + **algorithms**?")

Comment: Are any of you aware of the history of code-golf questions on SO?

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn I remember having them there. Then later having them all closed. Note however that Code Golf and CP have little to do with each other (I don't think that's what you hinted at either)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Competitive programming questions are just like any other programming question: they're a programming question.  As such, the [competitive-programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/competitive-programming) tag doesn't seem to me like a useful characterization.  How would such questions materially differ from other Stack Overflow questions?

The SO/Programmers/SE decision doesn't change based on the question being related to a coding contest.

Comment: They're in all likelihood a mixture of algorithm design and implementation, like almost all other questions in [algorithm]. There are however certain restrictions on what libraries you can use etc that are not present in other scenarios. For example you might not be able to use a BBST with subtree size augmentations, because it's tricky to implement and standard libraries don't offer it. Approximate algorithms or ones that only work well assuming some kind of input distribution are useless. Without reiterating this time after time in every question this results in wasted efforts by answerers

Comment: Another question would be if we should keep the two other tags in case we agree that it's not sensible to have a specific tag

Comment: Competitive programming is a world unto itself. Almost no best-practice advice that works for professional programming, applies to competitive programming. Such a tag would be highly salient in communicating the asker's context and expectations.